# MYSql query to get sum of amount date wise and Id wise

Tags: php, android, mysql

[image]

Please see the above table image to check how my table structure is.

I want sum of fct & amount date wise and according to repeating program codes.

The query i tried till now :

**Select ProgramId,Sum(FCT) as fct,Sum(Amount) as amount,Date From wap_program_revenue Where Date Between "2017-09-10" And "2017-09-15" Group By Date,ProgramId**

But this doesnt give desired output..I still see duplicate program codes whose fct & amount values are not added.

Please help and please do let me know if the issue is unclear.

Comment: first you need to add proper table definition with sample data using sqlfiddle/rextester or any online tool,  not in the form of images second include your expected result set in your post

Comment: the expected result is sum of fct/amount values for all the duplicate program id which should be date wise...

Comment: if you are grouping both datewise and programid wise you will obviously see duplicate programid for two different dates, can you please explain in detail your expected output.

Comment: i want sum of fct & amt date wise and of repeated program Id throughout the date range or else just print the fct & amt as it is

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still not clear. What do you mean by "of repeated program ID"?

Comment: see if there are duplicate program ids in the date range then add their respective fct and amt values and show the result...........................or if there is only single program id in the date range then simply display their respective fct and amount values..........this is what is expected